# Failed to start MySQL Community Server. in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I met a problem with mysql that can not boot:

```
Failed to start MySQL community server
```

Can't remember exactly how the problem started

[image]

Comment: What have you done about the two lower lines in the red box? "*No such file or directory*" and "*/var/lib/php/sessions*"

Comment: actually the session directory is exist root@ShafeelSha:/var/lib/php/session#

Comment: facing below error while restrt mysql , Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Then ask yourself why php apparently cannot find a directory that seems to exist. Common reasons: Permissions, typos, incorrect settings.

Comment: don't know  why like this  ?